# how to implement middleware in socket.io like express in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How to implement middleware like this in socket.io? Please help

**EXPRESS APP**

```
var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('LOGGED')
  next()
}

app.use(myLogger)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

**SOCKET APP** (I am using express pattern but its not working)

```
var myLogger = function (data,next) {
  console.log('DOING DATA VALIDATION...')
  next()
}

io.use(myLogger)

io.on('someEvent/', function (data, callback) {
  callback('Hello World!')
})
```

> Error : next() is not define!

Comment: A socket.io middleware function is only fired once per connection. So, this is not the best place for direct data validation. It gets the socket of the connection and a next callback; like `io.use( (socket, next) => { ... }` ).  The express app example is not necessary, it does not help us to help you. Instead show us the real error message and the complete code of the Socket App. Perhaps you did something wrong. (imports, intialization of io, ...) And of cause, the SOCKET APP must be on the server side. More infos here: https://socket.io/docs/v3/middlewares/

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.io = io;
    next();
});
```

This assigns a socket object to every request.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody's still wondering.

To use middleware on all sockets:

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
  // isValid is just a dummy function
  if (isValid(socket.request)) {
    next();
  } else {
    next(new Error("invalid"));
  }
});
```

This example is from the [official docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/) of socket.io

To use a middleware for a specific client:

```
io.on('connection', async (client) => {
    client.use((socket, next) => {
        console.log(`got event: ${socket[0]} in client middleware, moving on with next() just like in express`)
        next()
    });
    // rest of your code
    newConnection(client)
})
```